# 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python-2.7

I am pretty new to python, I'm playing around with the unittest and nosetests.

```
def revenue(r):
    return r * (1)

def profit (p):
    return p * (1.0-.05)

import unittest 
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
def test_revenue(self):
    self.assertEqual( revenue(0), 0 )
    self.assertEqual( revenue(10), 10)
    self.assertEqual( revenue(100), 100)

def test_profit(self):
    self.assertEqual( profit(0), 0)
    self.assertEqual( profit(10), 9.5)
    self.assertEqual( profit(100), 95)



unittest.main()
```

The unittest seems to work fine, but when I try to run the nosetests on it, it always fails with the same error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_employee'"

I feel there is probably a simple answer but I'm stumped, any help would be appreciated

"test_employee" is the name of the .py file.

the trace error I am getting is

### "ERROR: Failure: AttributeError ('module' object has no attribute 'test_employee')

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\nose\loader.py", line 418,in        loadTestsFromName
addr.filename, addr.module)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\nose\importer.py", line 47, in     importFromPath
return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\nose\importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
File "C:\Users\----\Localclone\test_employee.py", line 22, in <module>
unittest.main()
File "c:\python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 94, in __init__
self.parseArgs(argv)
File "c:\python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 149, in parseArgs
self.createTests()
File "c:\python27\lib\unittest\main.py", line 158, in createTests
self.module)
File "c:\python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 130, in loadTestsFromNames
suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
File "c:\python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 100, in loadTestsFromName
parent, obj = obj, getattr(obj, part)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_employee'"
```

Comment: Show us the complete error message, including any stack trace it might come with.

Comment: Where is the `test_employee` in your code?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the issue, but perhaps you should be guarding the call to `unittest.main()` with an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block? It looks like the unittest code is being run twice!

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks the nosetests works.